# How do I gain access to environment variables in a subsite that is in a separate package?

Tags: haskell, yesod

My Yesod subsite needs to write some files relative to the application's root directory.

[Looking at this](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/environment-variables), it appears a scaffolded Yesod site already does most of the plumbing, but how can I access this in a subsite that doesn't know about the `App` record?

`approot` itself is defined in the scaffolded Yesod project using a reference to `appSettings`, which is *also* an element of `App`:

```
approot = ApprootMaster $ appRoot . appSettings
```

Is there a function that gives me the application root (or at least a valid file path to the root directory) without having to know about the implementation details? Being able to reuse the existing Yesod functionality would be nicest, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the master site's fields without knowing the type of the master site itself, which generally defeats the purpose of having a subsite. Your typical options are:

1. Make the data you're looking for an explicit argument to the subsite
2. Require an extra typeclass constraint that the master site must be an instance of, that gets the data from the master site

yesod-static is a good example of the former approach; yesod-auth an example of the latter.

Comment: I can't seem to find where this is defined or used in yesod-static or yesod-auth. Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

    `saveToYesodRoot :: (YesodDataSource a) => FilePath -> IO ()        
    saveToYesodRoot file = do
     let root = (getAppRoot :: Approot a)
     return ()`


In short: I'd like to get the application's root, append a FilePath to it, and write a file to it. Approot is a data type that I'm also not sure how I could convert to an actual file path.